# JSON Response IBM BPM

Tags: json, ibm-bpm

In our environment we have to prepare the response call with a JSON format (`tw.local.jsonResponse`). I'm new to JSON, not sure how to parse the date with the following JSON format in IBM BPM. It could be a great help if anyone guide/suggest (by using the following data).

---

```
Success Response

Code: 200

Content:

{
        “status” : “success”
        “data” : {
                “change_number” : [string],
                “instance” : [string],
                “customer” : [string],
                “tasks” : [
                      { “task_number” : [string],
                        “description” : [string],
                        “schedule_start” : [datetime],
                        “schedule_end” : [datetime]
                      },
                      { /* another task */ }
                ]
        }
}
```

---

Comment: Is [this guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/BPM%20Help%20Wiki/page/Parsing%20JSON%20String%20Using%20BPM%20JSON%20Helper%20Toolkit%20and%20Dot%20Notation) any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar problem with json and dates in IBM BPM.

In your solution, you can get the external JavaScript file json.js.

You can use the following function to return your JSON string:

```
BPMJSON.convertTWToJSON(tw.local.MyObject, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is make BO with require Datatype with the same name of BO.
Then use the following code to convert twObject to JSON:-

```
function createJson(twObject){   
        var jsonString="";
        if(typeof twObject =='object' && twObject!=null){
            if(twObject.listLength>0){
                jsonString+="[";

                for (var j=0; j<twObject.listLength; j++){

        if(typeof twObject[j]!='string')
                  jsonString+="{";

                for (var property in twObject[j].propertyNames){

                       var name = twObject[j].propertyNames[property];
                       if(typeof twObject[j][name]=='object'){
                           if(Object.prototype.toString.call(twObject[j][name]).indexOf("TWDate")!="-1"){
                               jsonString+="\""+name+"\":\""+twObject[j][name].format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")+"\",";
                           }else{
                               jsonString+="\""+name+"\":"+createJson(twObject[j][name]);
                           }                     
                       }
                       else{
                           jsonString+="\""+name+"\":\""+twObject[j][name]+"\",";
                       }

                       if(twObject[j].listLength>0)
                       {
                         for (var k=0;k<twObject[j].listLength;k++){
                         jsonString+="\""+ twObject[j][k]+"\",";
                         }
                       }

                }
                   if(typeof twObject[j] == 'string'){
                   jsonString+="\""+twObject[j]+"\"";

                    }

                 if(typeof twObject[j]!='string')
                  jsonString+="}";




               if(j!=twObject.listLength-1){
                   jsonString+=",";
               }
    }    jsonString+="],";
            }else{
                try{
                if(twObject.propertyNames.length>0){
                jsonString+="{";
                 for(var property in twObject.propertyNames){

                       var name = twObject.propertyNames[property];
                       if(typeof twObject[name]=='object'){
                           if(Object.prototype.toString.call(twObject[name]).indexOf("TWDate")!="-1"){
                               jsonString+="\""+name+"\":\""+twObject[name].format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")+"\",";
                           }else{
                               jsonString+="\""+name+"\":"+createJson(twObject[name]);
                           }

                       }else{
                           jsonString+="\""+name+"\":\""+twObject[name]+"\",";
                       }


                    }
                 jsonString+="},"; }
                 else{
                     return "{},";
                 }}catch(e){
                     return "{},";
                 }
            }

      }
      else if(typeof twObject =='object' && twObject==null){
            return "{},";
        }
      return jsonString;
    }
```

Source Code:http://www.ibpmcoding.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked in BPM 8.6 for a Rest Token:

```
tw.local.authToken = JSON.parse(tw.system.invokeREST(request).content).access_token;
```

Explained part by part:

```
tw.system.invokeREST(request)
```

Invoke the REST client to make a call.

```
tw.system.invokeREST(request).content
```

Contains the response as a jsonstring.

```
JSON.parse(tw.system.invokeREST(request).content).access_token
```

Parses it back to a json object and extract the attribute access_token as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Humm.. I see why you have issue. Let me make it clear.

**JSON Dates are not dates – they are Strings!!**

So there is no fix format of date within JSON but we are lucky in case of IBM BPM.

String representation of date are in format of UTC time (indicated by the Z) in case of IBM BPM, for example

"2020-09-24T18:04:41.306Z"

You can convert this date string to JS Date on any browser using any date function for example

```
new Date("2020-09-24T18:04:41.306Z")
```

On server side JS you can use the same trick, converting sting date to JS date.